# Is there any mocking framework available for blackbox testing of windows and mac apps?

Tags: automated-testing, mock

We test a bunch of applications on windows, mac and mobile platforms. We use a tool called TPlan robot for our UI automation testing of those apps. Our testing is blackbox testing so there is no way to change the api calls that apps make. Is there any framework that can run a webserver to intercept api calls and replicate the responses to these apps?

PS: Sorry if my question is too generic and please let me know if you need more specifics. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are these apps web apps or desktop apps?

Comment: These are native desktop apps

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Charles Proxy's Re-Write Tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) to create rules for capturing certain requests or responses and change on aspects of them.

[image]

Comment: By looking at the basic introductions to this tool it seems like this is the tool I am looking for. Will research more on this tool. Thank you very much for the suggestion @joão-farias